# Mounted folder changes name after reboot

Tags: raspbian, usb, mount, fstab

I have Raspbian OS installed. My Raspberry Pi is used to save my ipcam snapshots. They are sent through ftp (proftpd) to a usb stick attached on my Rpi.
Mount point = `/dev/sda1`
`df -h`
[image]
Everything works fine until I reboot the device. Then the folder where `/dev/sda1` is mounted on changes in `/media/pi/USB1` with the result that my snapshots aren't saved anymore and I just get an empty folder.
I then have to unmount `\dev\sda1`, remove the automatically created folder 'USB1' folder and create a 'USB' folder again to see my files again. I also lose all the permissions I've set on folders and files previously in `/media/pi/USB`. 
I thought I had to unmount the usb first `/dev/sda1` before sending the reboot command. But that didn't resolved the problem. Again my path changed to `/media/pi/USB1`.
I'm novice to Linux. So every information is welcome. Should I for example read the fstab man pages? Is it there that I have to change settings?
`sudo fdisk -l`
[image]

Comment: If the filesystem on your USB stick is ext2/3/4, you can use something like `sudo e2label /dev/sda1 USBSTICK` and then add a line in your `/etc/fstab` that starts with `LABEL=USBSTICK /where/you/want/it/mounted ...`. See here... http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-centos-debian-fedora-mount-partition-label/

Comment: Thank you Mark. I learned about fstab and this works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Credits to Mark, and here is how I did it, this is my `/etc/fstab`:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p6  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p7  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
/dev/sda1       /media/pi/USB   ext4    defaults,rw       0       3
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

I've just added the line that starts with `/dev/sda1`. What I've read on forums is that it is important to keep in mind that you can apply the trick above only when you are using 1 USB storage device. When you have multiple, you have to work with UUID's. It's well explained [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Adding_USB_Drives).

Oh and for an explanation of the different columns you see in my code you can check [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/38125/htg-explains-what-is-the-linux-fstab-and-how-does-it-work/).